# Regex for broken links with whitespaces

Tags: java, regex, href

i am using this Regex

```js
private static final String HREF_PATTERN = 
    "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
```

to get the link from

```
 <a href=www.example.com/1234 5678>
```

The URL is malformed. It contains a whitespace. The Problem is that i want to get the whole link including "5678", but i only get "www.example.com/1234".

I am not that good with regular Expressions. Can someone please provide a valid regex so that i can get the whole url "www.example.com/1234 5678".

Thanks

Comment: Why would a URL contain whitespace? Usually spaces are converted to `%20`

Comment: The URL is being created from another program which i am not able to edit

Comment: Replace the withespaces with %20 then and keep your regex for valid urls

Comment: can't you provide the url inside the quotes and just get it from within?

Comment: Thats part of the Problem. The link is not within quotes. If it where within quotes the problem wouldn`t even exist. The external program creates an html Email with several <a href=www.example.com/1234 5678> tags. Replacing all Whitespaces is also not an option, because this would also remove all whitespaces from the email-text

Comment: Try `"\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">]+))"`. Unless your `<a>` tags contain other attributes, this will capture the whole href value. Or, you can just use a look-ahead to stop before the next attribute name: `(?i)\\s*href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">]+(?=\\s+\\w+=|>)))`

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for the regex. It works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The external program creates an html Email with several `<a href=www.example.com/1234 5678>` tags.

Assuming you cannot fix it on the source level, you can try fixing that with a regex.

*If the `href` attribute is the only attribute*, you just do not have to care about the spaces after `=`. Remove `\\s` from your pattern and it will work.

```
private static final String HREF_PATTERN = 
   "(?i)\\s*href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">]+))";
                                                     ^
```

If you have attributes with values, you will have to use a look-ahead:

```
private static final String HREF_PATTERN = 
    (?i)\\s*href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">]+(?=>|\\s+\\w+=)))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW6fY5/1)

However, this will not work with attributes like `nofollow`.